# Wiring 6 LEDs to a 9V battery with a voltage converter and switch

Tags: voltage-regulator

Ok before I get blasted for my ignorance, I haven't done anything like this in many years and still never grasped the core concepts. I have a lamp that I would like to wire up that will use 6 LED lights all wired to a 9V battery. A bad walkthrough of the setup (for this specific lamp) includes a voltage regulator (I'm honestly not sure what this is for and how to it will be used, 5V regulator module mini voltage reducer adjustable DC 4.5-24V) and a switch. I'm unsure on how to wire this when I have 6 wires all coming from different parts of the lamp and then what? All of the tutorials and guides I have seen are very simple wiring. I understand that this is very simple wiring to most people but I am trying to get a good idea on where to start.

I do realize that the voltage from 6 LEDs will add up to more than 9V. That is why I am curious about the voltage regulator and its usage. Plus I have a whole box of resistors. Just need some help keeping it clean and straight forward. I appreciate any and all recommendations and sorry for my stupidity. I figured this would be a relatively good starting point with tinkering with electronics.

Thank you!

Comment: LED specs?  Supply specs? Alk. or Li?  Duration expectations?

Comment: Why go to all that trouble when two (or three) LED's in series with a resistor work well from a 9V battery? Will the voltage reducer be more efficient??

Comment: which type of 9 V battery are you using?

Comment: You don't necessarily need a voltage converter. As in one of the earlier comment you aren't limited to having all of the LED's in series. You have the option of putting all six LED's in parallel or in three sets of two series/parallel groups.  Here is a simple tutorial from IEEE.  https://tryengineering.org/wp-content/uploads/LEDSandResistors.pdf

Comment: If you are fixed on driving all 6 LED's in series from a single 9v battery you would need a "Step-Up LED Driver". If you google that you will find hundreds of examples.

Comment: Sorry, I have a variety pack of LED lights that are both 3mm and 5mm. LEDs are 2.5V and 3.3V. AWG 20 copper wire, 9V connectors, 12mm vertical slide switches, and the voltage regulator. I don't really know what to say about the 9V battery? 9V alkaline battery, I'm not sure what else to say about it lol. Sorry for late comment